# Hiding during render doesn't seem to be working

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

Just did my first animation, so I may have done something wrong. Have a character with cartoon eyes, non-spherical, so I went with 3 eyelid covers anchored to the head bone and mirrored to do a step animation of a blink with the camera 'disable in render' on the lids. Worked fine in the stationary test but when I moved the character for the body animation the hidden eyelid cover showed on the eye although it didn't do the mirror for the other eye. When it came time to do the blink, the eyelids appeared in mid-air above the origin. Using versions 3.4 and 3.5

[image: Here's a picture of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I applied the mirror to the eyelids and the problem went away. Unfortunately, it also screwed up my keyframes, so I have to do the animation all over again.